# Cucumber parallel tests running good in local but throwing NPE on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

So we have used [Cucable](https://github.com/trivago/cucable-plugin) plugin for running our tests in parallel. Our framework(the part which causes the problem) is designed in this way -

DriverManager class initializes the driver through `initiateWebDriverInstance` method. We call this method from Hooks class. There is one static `instance` variable which will hold the reference to its object with the initialized driver.

DriverManager.java

```
public class DriverManager
{
     public static DriverManagerinstance;  // instance variable for DriverManager
     public WebDriver driver;
     public static String browsername = "chrome";

     public static DriverManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DriverManager();
        }
        return instance;
     }

     public void initiateWebDriverInstance(String browserName) {
        //initializing chrome driver
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //this is executing fine
     }

    //some code
}
```

Hooks.java

```
public class Hooks {

    @Before
    public void setup() {  

  DriverManager.getInstance().initiateWebDriverInstance(DriverManager.browsername);

}

 @After...
  }
```

Page1Steps.java

```
public class Page1Steps extends WebSessionManager {

    private WebDriver driver = WebSessionManager.getInstance().driver; //driver is null here only in Jenkins rest working fine
    private C2CWebLibrary webLibrary = new C2CWebLibrary(driver); //this is C2CLandingSteps.java:20
//some code
}
```

These tests are running fine on my local machine but they produce this on Jenkins machine -

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.cars24.library.C2CWebLibrary.(C2CWebLibrary.java:30)     at
>   steps.C2C.C2CLandingSteps.(C2CLandingSteps.java:20)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
>     at
>   org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)   at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)   at
>   cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)    at
>   cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)    at
>   org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:82)     at
>   org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:70)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:667)  at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.runJUnitWorkers(TestRunner.java:950)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:698)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:599)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)

Tests are running perfectly on my local machine. What may be wrong in this?

Comment: Is your framework or the plug-in implementing ThreadLocal at all?  That's what I've used to run parallel in Cucumber with TestNG

Comment: @BillHileman No we have not used ThreadLocal. I know what it is but that doesn't work for me. Can you please share an example of how would I implement it in my framework?

Comment: Can you point to the line of code in that rather lengthy stacktrace where the NPE is actually happening?  At what point does it fail?  Immediately?  Does it start one or more instances before failing?

Comment: @BillHileman Simply in Page1Steps.java, the driver wherever it may be used is being returned null

Comment: Must be related to the plug-in.  I don't know how you would do parallel testing without ThreadLocal or TestNG or Selenium Grid.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: @BillHileman you can refer to cucable plugin, I have mentioned link in the question. The tests run fine locally